# DeveDeNG crashes on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: iso, dvd

I'm trying to create an .iso image (for burning to a video DVD) on Ubuntu Focal from an .mp4 file. DeVeDeNG crashes without any message. I never had a problem with Ubuntu 18.04. Any ideas? Alternatively, is there another app which has this functionality?

Comment: Have you tried running it from a terminal screen to see if a message appears?  Open a terminal window and run `/usr/bin/devede` to see if any messages show up.

Comment: Are you missing a shared library? `ldd /usr/bin/devede` will tell you.

Comment: @waltinator ldd command gives: 
john@johnpc:~$ ldd /usr/bin/devede 
 not a dynamic executable

Comment: @Bovine Running from Terminal gives same result. I only realised after posting my question that DeVeDeNG app causes shutdown of Ubuntu. This is due to my Ubuntu Settings having a Blank Screen after 15 minutes (not long enough for DeVeDE to create the .iso) and Automatic Screen Lock at that point. I solved the problem by setting blank screen to Never and switching off Automatic Screen Lock. I have a feeling that I had to do this on Ubuntu 18.04 as well but I'd forgotten about it. Is there a way of reporting this to the DeVeDe developer(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only realised after posting my question that DeVeDeNG app causes shutdown of Ubuntu. This is due to my Ubuntu Settings having a Blank Screen after 15 minutes (not long enough for DeVeDE to create the .iso) and Automatic Screen Lock at that point. I solved the problem by setting blank screen to Never and switching off Automatic Screen Lock. I have a feeling that I had to do this on Ubuntu 18.04 as well but I'd forgotten about it.

Comment: I've reported this on Launchpad.